# Making the Navbar remain on top in all views when navbar is present in only one column - ReactJS

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, responsive-design, navbar

I am building a reactJS application in which the navbar is present only in middle column. But when I switch to mobile view, due to bootstrap by default the navbar comes below the first column. If I try to change the position to fixed-top it extends to all columns. I need it to stay in the middle in both lg and md views, but in small screens it should come above the first column. I have attached a screenshot.

[This is the application in desktop view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qRUVX.png)

[This is in mobile view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UMPtG.png)

How can I make this change in my website ??

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement a combination of css, media breakpoints, and some pure JS. Here's a working example.

- Switch the `nav` to `position: fixed;` at the mobile breakpoint, which I assume is `768`.
- Because fixed will remove it from the regular HTML element flow and place it overtop of other items, to account for that shift, add `margin-top` to the first container `.element-one` that is the same height as the nav + a few extra pixels to account for spacing.

```js
var navBreakpoint = 768,
    el1 = document.body.querySelector('.element-one');

navHeight();
window.addEventListener('resize', function(){
  navHeight();
});

function navHeight(){
  var mt = document.body.querySelector('nav').offsetHeight + 10,
      docWidth = document.body.clientWidth;
    
  if( docWidth < navBreakpoint ){ 
    el1.style.marginTop = mt+'px';
  } else {
    el1.style.marginTop = 'unset';
  }
}
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
}
.container > div {
  padding: 1rem;
  margin: 3px;
  border: 1px solid #efefef;
}
.container nav {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #efefef;
  background: #efefef;
}

@media(max-width: 768px){
  .container {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .container nav {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    left: 0;
    padding: 0.5rem;
  }
  .element-one {
    padding-top: 3rem;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
  <div class="element-one">
    Logo
  </div>
  <div class="element-two">
    <nav>I AM THE NAV</nav>
    Mi quis hendrerit dolor magna eget est lorem ipsum dolor. Tempor orci eu lobortis elementum nibh tellus molestie. Nulla facilisi morbi tempus iaculis urna.
  </div>
  <div class="element-three">
    A condimentum vitae sapien pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus. Eget mauris pharetra et ultrices neque ornare. Lorem mollis aliquam ut porttitor.
  </div>
</div>
```